# How many distinct area histograms I can get by partitioning a M x N rectangle?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, discrete-geometry

Given a $M \times N$ rectangle $r$, a partition $p$ of $r$ is a collection of rectangles with area smaller or equal than $r$ that cover $r$. The histogram of a partition $h(p)$ is the frequency distribution of rectangle areas in $p$.
For example, for a $2 \times 2$ rectangle, we can have only $4$ different histograms resulting from its partitions:

\begin{align}
p_1 &= [4,0,0,0];\\
p_2 &= [0,2,0,0];\\
p_3 &= [2,1,0,0];\\
p_4 &= [0,0,0,1]; 
\end{align}
where $p_n[i]$ is the # of rectangles of area $i$ in the partition (the array is one-based).

Note that the smaller possible rectangle is $(1,1)$, and only rectangles with integer dimensions are considered.

So how can I count the number of distinct histograms resulting from all possible partitions of a $M \times N$ rectangle?

The problem is very similar to [this](http://www.dubberly.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/3x4variations-poster.pdf), but in that problem order and position matter, while in my problem all I care about is the distribution of rectangle areas.

Comment: Presumably, you want the rectangles to be disjoint and parallel to the original rectangle and of integer sizes?

Comment: That's correct, @ThomasAndrews Maybe the correct term is tessellation...